# How to check which submission button was clicked?

Tags: filters, hooks, customization

So I added a new submission button to the edit page:

Using the `post_submitbox_misc_actions` hook with the `submit_button($text, $type, $name);` function.

I wanted to modify the data that's saved based on what button the user clicks. So if the user clicks on the regular update/submit button then the post would save normally. However if the user clicks on the new button, then I would modify some information about that post.

I was planning to use the `wp_insert_post_data` hook to modify the data, but the problem is that I don't know what button the user clicked (using php).

So my question... is it possible to identify which button the user clicked using a hook (or some other method)?

Or, is this not the correct approach? And I should use some other method to interfere the save action?

Update:

I also tried logging $_GET and $_POST to see if there was any relevant information there, but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function [`submit_button()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/submit_button) does generate:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="button button-primary" value="Save Changes"  />
```

As seen on the codex documentation page. Which gives you the possibility to check for a `$_POST` or, depending on the form, `$_GET` or generic `$_REQUEST` variable - to be exact for `$_POST[ 'submit' ]` or `$_GET[ 'submit' ]` or `$_REQUEST[ 'submit' ]`. The key for the variable is determined by the `input` tags `name` attribute value, which you can change for `submit_button()` by making use of the `$name` parameter.

Comment: Gotcha.  I was expecting to see something like  $_POST['submit'] = 'my_submit_button_value", where the array key is always 'submit', but the value changes according to the name attribute. But instead, what I see is the key as the submit button 'name' and the value as the submit button 'value'. So I just need to check of the key exists, and if it matches the value.

Comment: Totally forgot to explain the value part, but you figured it out yourself anyway. I would figure that should be enough to determine the button pressed, right?  @gdaniel

Comment: @gdaniel My pleasure!